# Input TYPE TEXT Value form (enctype=“multipart/form-data”) returns null

Tags: http, go

```
func fupload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        r.ParseForm()
        company := r.FormValue("company")
        fmt.Println(company)
        _, header, _ := r.FormFile("upfile")
        fmt.Println(header.Filename)
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte("<html><body>"))
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("<form method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">")))
    w.Write([]byte("Enter Company <input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"80\" size=\"80\" name=\"company\" ><br/>"))
    w.Write([]byte("File to upload: <input type=\"file\" name=\"upfile\" /><br/>"))
    w.Write([]byte("<input type=\"submit\"  value=\"Submit\"/>"))
    w.Write([]byte("</form>"))
    w.Write([]byte("</body></html>"))
    return
}
```

For the input type Text (eg) Company here always return NULL, when enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 2):

[`ParseForm`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) only parses the query parameters. From the docs:

> ParseForm parses the raw query from the URL and updates r.Form.
>
> For POST or PUT requests, it also parses the request body as a form
>   and put the results into both r.PostForm and r.Form. POST and PUT body
>   parameters take precedence over URL query string values in r.Form.
>
> If the request Body's size has not already been limited by
>   MaxBytesReader, the size is capped at 10MB.
>
> ParseMultipartForm calls ParseForm automatically. It is idempotent.

Either use [`ParseMultipartForm`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm) if you want to handle "multipart/form-data", or don't call either and let `FormValue` call what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use enctype="multipart/form-data". But you should not use ParseForm() method if you already use FormValue(key string) or FormFile(key string) method.

[Request.FormFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile)

> FormFile returns the first file for the provided form key. FormFile
>   calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary.

[Request.FormValue](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue)

> FormValue returns the first value for the named component of the
>   query. POST and PUT body parameters take precedence over URL query
>   string values. FormValue calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if
>   necessary and ignores any errors returned by these functions. If key
>   is not present, FormValue returns the empty string. To access multiple
>   values of the same key, call ParseForm and then inspect Request.Form
>   directly.

```
<form action="/fupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="fileupload">
</form>


file, _, err := req.FormFile("fileupload")
    switch err {
    case nil:
        defer file.Close()
        fileData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        //check err
    case http.ErrMissingFile:
        //do something
    default:
        //do something
    }
```